# how can i get my ip address on my wifi router with python

Tags: python, ip

I want get my ip address on my router(for example: **192.168.1.xxx**
i use `gethostbyname()` but is show **127.0.0.1**

Answer (score 1):

To get the router that your PC is connected to you can try getting the IP of the default gateway that your PC is using - since your PC will most likely use the router as the default gateway.

Use `netifaces` for that:

```
import netifaces

gw = netifaces.gateways()

print(gw['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0])
```

Which gives:

```
192.168.1.1
```

In my case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to stop working if you have mapping to 127.0.0.1 in your HOSTS file. Instead I will use `getfqdn()` (To get fully qualified domain name):

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()))
```